# 10Gb network. Can browse share (samba/nfs) from clients, but initiating a copy takes server's network down?

Tags: centos, networking, file-copy

I don't really know where to start, as I'm not very familiar with Linux at all.

We have a LTO6 tape system bought in 2014 from Cache-A running CentOS. It came pre-installed and configured, ready to use, with both 1Gb ethernet and 10Gb ethernet adapters. End of support/end of life for the system was 1st January, 2018.

**Details:**
Centos-version: 6-2.el6.centos7.x86_64
Linux kernel version: 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
10Gb NIC = NC552SFP
NC552SFP Driver/Kernel Module: nx_nic
NX_NIC version: 4.0.556
NC552SFP Firmware: 4.0.579

The system has up until now been connected using 1Gb ethernet, and there are no problems copying data to/from the system using 1Gb.

We have recently installed a Cisco SG550XG 10Gb switch to set up a small 10Gb network between a couple of NAS boxes and some clients. I would also like to get our LTO system up and running on 10Gb.

I can mount the server's share from a 10Gb client (Windows 10), either by Samba or NFS.

I've also tested doing the same from a laptop with ZorinOS (Ubuntu), which I connected to the Cisco switch so it would use the 10Gb IP-range. I can ping the server from the clients. I've also tested using mtu size 1500 and 9000 on both server, switch and clients. I've tested doing a direct connection as well.

I can browse the share via 10Gb, but when I initiate a copy process of some files (from the share to the client), the copy process just hangs and never start. (Windows 10 says "Calculating time.."

When I take a closer look on the server, its 10Gb network link is actually lost, and in the terminal I can't even display info about the ethernet interface no more. (For example `ethtool eth2`)

I have to restart the server to be able to get the NIC up and running again.

As this happens with both Samba and NFS, from both Windows 10 and ZorinOS, I don't think it's related to either Samba or NFS configuration.

Any suggestions for how I can isolate and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider an firmware upgrade and driver upgrade of your 10 Gb Network card.
From [Driver & Software HP Sites](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5154775&swItemId=MTX_830ab86848364752b6caab7aef&swEnvOid=4184#tab5):

> Known Issue:
>    Firmware 4.2.401.6 or later is not compatible with Red Hat 6 update 2   (Red Hat 6.2) x64 Inbox NIC driver (version 4.1.255.11). In order to upgrade to Firmware 4.2.401.6 or later,  you must first upgrade to Red Hat 6.2x64 driver version 4.2.392.1 or later.

It seems like you never perfom this operation before according to your firmware version.
I will not be able to help you more than this though.